# How to parse twilio notification API request response

Tags: json, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am working with twilio latest `php sdk 6.10`. Here I am trying to make notifications API calls to send bulk messages.
It is working fine But the request Response it returns is not in proper `json` format. Instead I am getting something like custom object attributes as

```
Twilio\Rest\Notify\V1\Service\NotificationInstance Object
(
    [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Notify\V1 Object
        (
            [_credentials:protected] => 
            [_services:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Notify\V1\ServiceList Object
                (
                    [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Notify\V1 Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [solution:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [uri:protected] => /Services
                )

            [domain:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Notify Object
                (
                    [_v1:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Notify\V1 Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [client:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Client Object
                        (
                            [username:protected] => sidddddddddddddd555555555555555
                            [password:protected] => jk44444444444444555555555555555
                            [accountSid:protected] => sighhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh44444444
                            [region:protected] => 
                            [edge:protected] => 
                            [httpClient:protected] => Twilio\Http\CurlClient Object
                                (
                                    [curlOptions:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
```

How can I make it return response in proper `json` format?
This is how I am making Send Requests

```
 $notification = $client
    ->notify->services($messagingServiceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => $binding,
    "body" => $sms_text
 ]);
```

or how can I fetch required data from this type of response?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio PHP library doesn't return the raw JSON to you. Instead it parses it and turns it into a PHP object that you can call on to retrieve the data or make further API calls with.

The object you have there is a `NotifcationInstance`, the docs for which are here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/6.10.3/classes/Twilio_Rest_Notify_V1_Service_NotificationInstance.html.

And the source code, including all the properties, is here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/main/src/Twilio/Rest/Notify/V1/Service/NotificationInstance.php

So you can get the data by calling on the properties of the instance:

```php
 $notification = $client
    ->notify->services($messagingServiceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => $binding,
    "body" => $sms_text
 ]);

 echo $notification->sid;
 echo $notification->body;
```